# How to index field with comma-separated text value - hibernate search

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I am implementing a book search function based on hibernate search3.2.

Book object contains a field called authornames. Authornames value is a list of names and comma is the splitter, say "John Will, Robin Rod, James Timerberland"

```
@Field(index = org.hibernate.search.annotations.Index.UN_TOKENIZED,store=Store.YES)
@FieldBridge(impl=CollectionToCSVBridge.class)
private Set<String> authornames;
```

I need each of names to be UN_TOKENIZED, so that user search book by single author name: John Will, Robin Rod or James Timerberland.

I used Luke to check indexs, and value in authornames field is stored as "John Will, Robin Rod, James Timerberland", but I can not get result by querying "authornames:John Will"

Anybody can tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I gues *CollectionToCSVBridge* is concatenating all names with a ", " in a larger string.
You should keep them separate instead and add each element individually to the index:

```
@Override
public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
    if ( value == null ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( !( value instanceof Collection ) ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "This FieldBridge only supports collections." );
    }
    Collection<?> objects = (Collection<?>) value;

    for ( Object object : objects ) {
        luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument( name, objectToString( object ), document ); // in your case objectToString could do just a #toString
    }
}
```

See also https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1015286&start=0